# Magento 2 : How to add a shipping charges via Cart price Rules?

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules

In Magento 2 It is possible to add shipping charge if specific category product is available in cart.

If not then please suggest me another way.

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature is available but you can do this by creating the cart rule.

Please follow the below guidelines

Go to the below location

> Magento_admin > Marketing > Promotion > Cart Price Rule

Click on **Add New Cart**

Fill the form for the **customer groups** select the appropriate customer to whom you want this rules to be applied, in the **coupon dropdown** select **`No coupon`** so that no one require to apply the coupon for getting free shipping, select the date range.

Now Go to the Actions tab, there in Discount Amount give 0

For the **`Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items)`** section follow the below things.

- Click on the plus button [please refer](https://www.screencast.com/t/AEDOnLIYg)
- Select **Category** from the first dropdown [please refer](https://www.screencast.com/t/WyMM0w2OHJc)
- From the second dropdown select **is one of**, [please refer](https://www.screencast.com/t/xloT6OOSHpZO)
- Click on the **...** & click on the **open chooser** [please refer](https://www.screencast.com/t/mp0KEHBgPh) select the categories in which you want to apply free shipping [please refer](https://www.screencast.com/t/d5VBgyFCc)
- In the **Free Shipping** dropdown select **`For matching items only`**.

Save the cart rule & set the required shipping method that you want to apply on the specific categories that you have not selected into the cart price rule & now test it it will work

> **Explanation:** Here what we have created is we have created a shipping method for all
>   the products/categories & then we created a cart rule to eliminate
>   those categories on which you don't want to apply the shipping charge.
>   So ultimately you are having the feature of shipping method on the
>   specific categories but in different manner. :)

Comment: Sir, I want to add shipping charges not reduce charges.

Comment: Cart price rule & catalog price rule is a feature for providing the discount on the products & the shopping total amount it is not for adding extra amount into the shipping amount.

Comment: Alternatively is what you can do is add the shipping amount to all the products & increase the price of the products & create the shipping method with that extra amount what you want to add on those category products & then apply the above rule

Comment: I got your point, Thanks